# height in Html email: td with image beside td with background-color

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I built an html document for newsletter which I will send from Outlook 2013.
Here is the Html [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/idoshhh/vztdg4ja/)

When I try to send it from the outlook the background color TD crossing the boundaries of the top and bottom row.

Can anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here is the prtscreen of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first things first - sending an email out of Outlook is going to ruin your code.  Outlook rewrites everything into WordHTML. There is no if, ands or buts about it, it is going to happen as soon as you insert the html into the new email.  This also includes that it will strip out any media queries, so responsive design is gone. I would highly recommend using another email client that can send HTML emails (e.g. Thunderbird) or an ESP (e.g. Exact Target, Mail Chimp) to send this out.

Now back to the issue you were asking about. The issue is the padding you have on the TD. Remove the padding and it fits.  If you want the padding on left and right, I would use "padding-left" and "padding-right" only. I would recommend having the bg run behind the image as well so if the height of the TD is increased due to variance of rendering across email clients, it makes it look like it is a border instead of a mistake.